# SED Unix command, need help to change .less files into style.css

Tags: regex, unix, sed

My intentions is to make all *.less files into style.css

I am not very familiar with this sed, however I have worked this out thanks to:
http://forums.devshed.com/unix-help-35/unix-find-and-replace-text-within-all-files-within-a-146179.html

```
for file in $(grep -rl ".less" *.php)
do
    sed -e "s/\/*.less/\/style.css/ig" $file > /tmp/tempfile.tmp
    mv /tmp/tempfile.tmp $file
done
```

Now this takes my files:

```
css/somefile.less
css/somefileagain.less
css/style.css
index.php
```

which is linked to in the php document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/somefile.less" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/somefileagain.less" />
```

My result becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/somefile/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/somefileagain/style.css" />
```

Which is not what I want. I want to get it to be the same path, and I think what I am missing is the * in the regexp which isn't replaced by the sed. Is there any way to get that working, my try was to make it look like this: (and I want to replace everything from / to .less with /style.css)

```
\/*.less
```

And still that doesn't work, maybe this approach is not the best, I need some advices if there is any flags that would replace the * as well, thanks.

Another issue I got is I cannot use -r/-R/--recursive in grep and I dont know why, I am running Debian. Any tips is appreciated.

/Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use following sed command inside your for loop:

```
sed -i.bak "s~/[^/]*\.less"~/style.css"~g" $file
```

No need to store sed's output in a separate file and then mv that temp file back to original. All this can be done with `-i` option.

Comment: Brilliant, that works great, one row instead of two as well. Got any clue about the last issue with grep?

Comment: I'll have to love -i from now on :)

Comment: @Oldek The issue is not with `grep` it is with your `loop`. If you are on `bash 4` you can enable `globstar` and drill down recursively so that your `grep` can identify all file. Or you can use `find` command something like this `find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec grep -rl ".less" {} \;`

Comment: This works but perhaps does not match what was intended. If you change the `"`'s for `'`'s i.e. `'s~/[^/]*\.less'~/style.css'~g'` you can see that it is 2 quoted strings with an unquoted string between.

Comment: @Oldek : YOu can try this grep command at the start: `grep -Rl "\.less" *.php` and If recursive isn't supported on Debian then you can try: `find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec grep -l "\.less" {} \;`

Comment: This did work for me: grep -rl ".less" */*.php - Also I would like to know if there are any good guides for this, I now would like to tweak it to replace everything within the cites, href="/less/somefolder/file1.less" (replace url with /css/style.css for example) - Any goof guides out there?

Comment: There are tons of guider/tutorials on Sed, Google is your friend. If you are struck at something feel free to create a question at SO. You'll get speedy answers here.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -i 's|[^/]*\.less|style.css|ig' $file
```